# Converting .eps to .jpg

Tags: image-processing, postscript, eps

Our print team saves raster images as .eps files. We need to convert about 11000 .eps to .jpg. We are using ImageMagick (with Ghostprint) on Linux. The conversion occurs but the resulting .jpg is not the same size as the source .eps - It's about 1/2 the size. Probably a problem converting a vector to a raster. Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your using the default resolution (72dpi). use the `-density` option to specify a dpi to `convert`.

`convert -density 300 /path/to/file.eps -flatten /path/to/file/.jpg;`

Comment: Something's changed in 11 years: "convert-im6.q16: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PS' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/421."